# Deriving sound speed from kinetic theory

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, acoustics, gas

The classical derivation for the sound speed involves using the ideal gas, isentropic, and momentum conservation equations, yielding $c_{\rm s} {=} \sqrt{\gamma k_{\rm B}T/\mu}$. If the gas is isothermal, the isentropic equation is not required and $c_{\rm s} {=} \sqrt{k_{\rm B}T/\mu}$.

How would I arrive at these sound speeds through kinetic theory? In other words, by considering particle velocities, collisions, etc. how would I arrive at these equations? I am aware that through the Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution one can derive various characteristic speeds, such as the mean ($\sqrt{8 k_{\rm B}T/\left(\pi\mu\right)}$), most common (i.e., mode; $\sqrt{2 k_{\rm B}T/\mu}$), and mean square speeds ($\sqrt{3 k_{\rm B}T/\mu}$).

**Parameters:**

- $\gamma=$ heat capacity ratio
- $k_{\rm B}=$ Boltzmann constant
- $T=$ temperature
- $\mu=$ molecular weight

Comment: Sound is a bulk phenomenon involving a pressure wave, this looks quite difficult.